# c# attempting to overload a cast from short to bool

Tags: c#, casting

I am attempting to overload a cast to short from a boolean. (true is 1 false is 0)

not quite sure how to go about it.
here was my attempt.

here is the fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/STWWfy

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.x = (short)false;
    }
}

public class MyClass
    {
      public short x {get; set;}
    }

public static implicit operator short(bool v)
{
    return (short)(v ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this in C# - you can only specify conversions to/from types which you define.

Comment: (short) false, you can't do that, you have to specifically say false is 0 and 1 is true

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to do this? As @canton says you can't do this the way you've shown, but perhaps there's an alternative.

Comment: `var x = Convert.ToInt16(true)` returns `1`... `Convert.ToInt16(false)` returns 0.

Comment: for explanation as to why. a sql server GIS database was recently updated and all of the bits were converted to smallint.  I am not allowed to change them back to bit.

Comment: @Ron Beyer thanks that is perfect

Comment: An alternative option is just create an extension: `public static short ToShort(this bool v) => v? (short)1 : (short)0;` and then `myObject.x = false.ToShort();`. TBH there's no need as there's the `Convert` class as already well mentioned here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are built-in methods to do this, see the [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
var x = Convert.ToInt16(true);   // x == 1
var y = Convert.ToInt16(false);  // y == 0
```

As others have said, you can't write your own conversions, only for types that you define.